# Retain last 5 visits by Person in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I have the following that contains dates, the visit number, and a specific variable of interest. I would like to retain the last five visits that are available in SAS by person. I am familiar with retaining the first and last visits. The data for a single subject is listed below:

```
Person        Date           VisitNumber           VariableOfInterest
001          10/10/2001                1                           6
001          11/12/2001                3                           8
001          01/05/2002                5                           12
001          03/10/2002                6                           5
001          05/03/2002                8                           3
001          07/29/2002               10                           11
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the last five observations that the person?  Or the values of VIsitNumber that are within 5 of the last VisitNumber?  For your example should the result be 5 observations or 3?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you like to see? Do you want to produce a dataset with 1 record per person each with 5 columns indicating those dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double DOW loop will let you *measure* the group in the first loop and select from the group based on your desired per-group criteria in the second loop.  This is useful when `have` is large and pre-sorted, and you want to avoid additional sorting.

```
data want;
  * measure the group size;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.person);
    set have;
    by person visitnumber; * visitnumber in by only to enforce expectation of orderness;
  end;
  _i_ = _n_;
  * apply the criteria "last 5 rows in group";
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if _i_ - _n_ < 5 then output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is easier if you sort by descending VisitNumber so that the problem becomes take the first 5 observations for a person.  Then just generate a counter of which observation this is for the person and subset on that.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  by person descending visitnumber;
  if first.person then rowno=0;
  rowno+1;
  if rowno <= 5;
run;
```